# Redirecting more than 6k individual pages to a new url structure: use htaccess or http redirects?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, pagerank

We are moving a site that was built directly in html to a new wordpress cms. Since the site depends largely on google searches it's fundamental not to lose the previous links. But here's the kicker:

1) All old URLs were built in a random manner, he simply uploaded a new file to the server everytime he wanted to create a new page ("somedirectory/page_about_something-4.html") and they will be recreated in wordpress using completelly new urls ("thenewcategory/page-title/"). So it will be impossible to have simply one regex line in htacess, I'll probably need to have a case per case redirect

2) there are more than 6 thousand pages that need redirection. I can't imagine what sort of impact on performance  having a .htaccess file would have.

So what are my options here? I'm imagining I could simply keep the old files on the server and make each one of them as a individual http redirect, but I'm afraid this might impact on our google page rank.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do make sure you give them 301 telling the SEO it's moved [permanent](http://webdesign.about.com/od/http/qt/tip301v302redir.htm)

Also take a look at this:
[.htaccess redirect performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209209/htaccess-redirect-performance)

Comment: But is there a way to have a 301 code without using htaccess? Because if I need to create one redirect line for each of the 6 thousand pages in my site I will quickly approach the "mosntrosity" of a 1mb htaccess file!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding 6k Rewrite rules in .htaccess it is much better to use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) for this case. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899805/edit-htaccess-with-php/8901022#8901022) as an example on using RewriteMap.