# .htaccess code slow down website?

Tags: .htaccess

I was curious if the htaccess code below can have any negative impact on a website with speed or SEO? What it does is redirect a user to a specific page if they have a particular IP address.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^58\.97\.142\.79$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^96\.248\.38\.64$
RewriteRule !\.(html)$ http://www\.website\.com/moved\.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a negative impact, but no, it is not something that should concern you, for the most part.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209209/htaccess-redirect-performance), the biggest impact is the file-read rather than the rule-processing.

According to [this blog post](http://simon.net.nz/articles/benchmarking-htaccess-performance/), the impact is approximately 2.3% faster to use an alternative like Apache's httpd.conf modifications over .htaccess.  This is not an appreciable difference.